# Missing template Error in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and I am facing this error whenever I try to reload the server page and actually I tried almost all the provided solutions for this problem asked by other people and nothing helped

> **Missing template home/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw,
>   :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *
>   "/Users/Bassem/Qulb/app/views" *
>   "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/views"
>   * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views"**

***ps: I am not using haml and I also tried rendering nothing inside it***

All what I did in my app is just implementing devise and adding these things to my

**application.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Qulb</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-3" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>



  <%= yield %>

  </div>




</body>
</html>
```

and here is it my **routes.rb**

```js
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
end
```

and finally my **home_controller**

```js
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to books_path if user_signed_in?
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When you hit an action in Rails, in your case index action, *it automatically render its template with templates name matching the name of its action*. In your case when you send a request to index action of home controller, ***user is not signed in so rails is looking for a template views/home/index.html.erb***, but you don't have that template there, causing your error.

For details on how things work in rails, checkout [`rail guides`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)